# Assert var set via <input ng-model> is not undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to enable or disable a button based on the value entered into an `<input>` tag. The field can be left blank or an int > 0 must be entered so, I want to assert that as long as `limitMatches` is not `undefined`.

I've configured my `input` tag as:

```
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" ng-model="query.limitMatches"/>
```

In the Angular controller:

```
$scope.query = {limitMatches: null};
$scope.searchAllowed = function() {
    typeof $scope.query.limitMatches !== "undefined";
};
```

However, my `searchAllowed` function is always returning true even though within the console (using `console.log($scope.query.limitMatches);`) I can see `limitMatches` is apparently set to `undefined`.

Comment: @devqon Quotes are necessary.

Comment: @devqon `typeof` returns a string containing the type. Because he is using double equals, the types are compared as well as the values, so the quotes are definitely needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution!

Turns out I needed wrap the `typeof $scope.query.limitMatches !== "undefined";` in brackets...

```
$scope.searchAllowed = function() {
    (typeof $scope.query.limitMatches !== "undefined");
};
```

What a kicker!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `undefined` is not strictly equal to `null`, that's why your function returns true event for "undefined" model.

I would simplify the function to react the same for any falsy value:

```
$scope.searchAllowed = function() {
    return Boolean($scope.query.limitMatches);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does ensure that the value entered is above the minimum. However, in this particular case I also wanted empty to be an acceptable value, still I'm confident plenty will find it useful :)